# Copying CSV file to on-premise SQL Server -BCP utility C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, bcp

I am trying to load a CSV file to on premise SQL Server, I tried to use BCP utility in my C# code, here is what I have done and facing below error.

Note: I have created a SQL table name AzureBlob  with 2 columns already with no data in it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string strCmdText;
    strCmdText = "/C bcp master..AzureBlob out C:\\data\\blbTest.csv -S .\\ -c -C RAW -T";
    Process process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = strCmdText;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Close();
    process.Dispose();
}
```

I receive below message however, it does not copy any records to the SQL table: Any pointers

Starting Copy
0 rows copied

My sample CSV file has two columns with sample text in it:
ColumnA ColumnB
Hello    World

Comment: You could execute BCP using BULK INSERT Transact-SQL statement and you could do it using ExecuteNonQuery method of SqlCommand.

Comment: If you are loading the table from a file, the direction should be `in` instead of `out`. I suggest you avoid using the master system database for user tables.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you , I have amended the command as below and still no luck.        ```strCmdText = "/C bcp msdb..AzureBlob in C:\\PoornimaDevelop\\BlobQuickstartV12\\data\\blbTest.csv -S .\\ -c -C RAW -T";```

Comment: @DaleK Question amended. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

It's been quite some time since I last used BCP, but if memory serves me right, you need to have the CSV file on the SQL Server storage - not locally on your computer in order for the import to work.

Comment: BCP is a client application so it can run anywhere with access to the file and server, not to be confused with the T-SQL `BULK INSERT` statement, where the database engine needs access to the file.